# Iterate through list, print iterable if the condition is met

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I have a list, containing random items, some of them consists of both numbers and letters.

```
my_list = ["a a1", "b 2b", "c c", "d d"]
```

I need to print items that are only consisting of letters.
I tried

```
for i in my_list:
    for j in i.split():
        if j.isalpha():
            print j
```

but it returns only

```
c c
d d
```

I also tried

```
for i in my_list: 
    if any(n.isalpha() for n in i.split()):
        print n
```

but it returns

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

I also need to print the initial contents of my_list, subtracting numbers from letters So it should look like this

```
a a
b b
c c
d d
```

I tried this:

```
for i in my_list:
    if all(n.isalpha() for n in i.split()):
        print i.title()
    elif any(n.isalpha() == False for n in i.split()):
        print n
```

but the abovementioned error occurs

```
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

So in the example with "a a1", I need to find the part of the string which does not contains numbers and print it and find the part which contains a number, subtract it and print. I got stuck with this.

Comment: Your output is what it should be I thought. It printed only the letters...

Comment: Shouldn't that be `name 'n' is not defined`?

Comment: As others are saying, the first block works instead of failing, and the second block has a different error.

Comment: You first block of code _should_ print exactly what you want to have (it does so for me). If you really get the output that you posted, then there must be something wrong with your input strings. My guess is that those are not really space characters but something else that merely looks like spaces.

Comment: You are absolutely right @tobias_k. I'll try to add more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in my_list:
   if all([j.isalpha() for j in i.split()]):
          print i #this will print the whole item e.g c c
```

Comment: This only prints what OP's code is (allegedly, though I can't reproduce) now printing, and what seems not to be what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it won't print a and b. I need to output
a
b
c c
d d

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in my_list:
    for j in i:
        if j.isalpha():
            print j
```

Since you didn't specify what format the output needs to be. This will do what you want. You were close though.

Comment: "Since you didn't specify what format the output needs to be" So, what makes you think that _this_ is what OP wants?

Comment: It outputs all the item with only one letter in one line